# How to mock DragEventArgs

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to unit test this method that is called from my ViewModel:

```
  public virtual string[] ExtractFilePaths(DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
  {
     string[] droppedPaths = null;

     if (dragEventArgs.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     {
        droppedPaths = dragEventArgs.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
     }

     return droppedPaths;
  }
```

I have this method wired up with Caliburn. I know it's a pretty simple method that almost exclusively uses framework classes, but I feel it still needs testing. The problem is, Moq cannot mock the DragEventArgs. Is there a way around this or should I just not bother testing this method?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully I am not missing anything with Calibrun, but why mock `DragEventArgs` when you can create one? The important part is the `IDataObject` part, which is an interface and can easily be mocked.

```
[Test]
public void ExtractFilePaths_WithFileDrop_ReturndDropPaths()
{
    var fileList = new[] {@"c:\path\path\file1.txt", @"d:\path2\path2\file2.txt"};
    var stubData = Mock.Of<IDataObject>(x =>
                                        x.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) == true &&
                                        x.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) == fileList);

    var dragEventArgs = new DragEventArgs(stubData, 0, 0, 0, DragDropEffects.Move, DragDropEffects.Scroll);

    var subject = new Subject();

    // Act
    var result = subject.ExtractFilePaths(dragEventArgs);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null, "Expected array to be returned");
    Assert.That(result, Is.EquivalentTo(fileList));
}
```

Comment: That's for System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs which has public constructor. System.Windows.DragEventArgs (WPF) is public sealed class and has no public constructor.

Comment: Thanks for making it sealed with an internal constructor.  God forbid we should be able to unit test our code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace DragEventArgs class with only the data you want to use in your function. DragEventArgs  belongs to UI, not ViewModel.

Comment: You need a DragEventArgs instance to invoke your event handler code in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you need is internal rather than public. You can call this constructor using reflection to create the event instance you need for unit testing.

```
Mock<IDataObject> dataObjectMock = new Mock<IDataObject>();
DragDropKeyStates dragDropKeyStates = DragDropKeyStates.LeftMouseButton;
DragDropEffects allowedEffects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
DependencyObject target = new DependencyObject();
Point point = new Point();

ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(DragEventArgs).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single();

object[] arguments = new object[]
{
    dataObjectMock.Object,
    dragDropKeyStates,
    allowedEffects,
    target,
    point
};

DragEventArgs dragEventArgs = (DragEventArgs)constructor.Invoke(arguments);
```